# Linux Distribution with out of the box (preferably at setup time) Active Directory authentication support?

Tags: linux, active-directory, installation

Title says it all. There are a few older questions here and other webpages with many years old answers - and I haven't stumbled on any that are truly out of the box.

Ideally there would be a distribution with a checkbox that says "join and use Windows Active Directory" for authentication. Followed by a prompt for a network admin login to kick off the join.

The goal is to recycle a couple computers using a relatively common Linux distribution to get a modern web browser, and have users be able to use their existing regular network login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL/CentOS 7 and Fedora include GNOME which allows you to set up enterprise login on first boot, when installed with the Workstation feature set. Just click "Set up Enterprise Login", choose your domain (which should be autodetected if DNS is working), and log in as a user authorized to enroll computers in the domain.

When not installed with Workstation, they can still be joined to the domain with the `realm join` command. For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# realm join ad.exmaple.com -U domainenrolluser
```